# Authentication to Unity Analytics using POST request

Tags: python, rest, unity-game-engine

I have a python script that should work, but it didn't. The status of the POST request is 401 - Unauthorized, but I am not 100% sure that my credentials are not valid or the problem is somewhere else.

Method:

```
def request_raw_analytics_dump(unity_project_id, unity_api_key, start_date, end_date, dump_format, data_set,
                               continue_from=None):
    uri = 'https://analytics.cloud.unity3d.com/api/v2/projects/' + unity_project_id + '/rawdataexports'

    postBodyJson = {'endDate': end_date, 'format': dump_format, 'dataset': data_set}

    if continue_from is not None:
        postBodyJson['continueFrom'] = continue_from
    else:
        postBodyJson['startDate'] = start_date

    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(uri, json.dumps(postBodyJson), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(unity_project_id, unity_api_key),
                      headers=headers)
    print('status'+str(r.status_code))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()['id']

    return None
```

Status is printed as 401 and I am getting None instead of data.
I get Project ID from Unity Dashboard, and this is good for sure. The problem is with API Key because I am not sure if I get the proper one:

[image]

Comment: Well, according to the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAnalyticsRawDataExport.html) this should work .. assuming that AppID and APIKey are indeed correct ;) Have you tried print the complete URL and projectID and apiKey just to be sure

Comment: So I printed these things and everything looks fine to me. Uri is like in Unity Documentation - https://analytics.cloud.unity3d.com/api/v2/projects/{UNITY_PROJECT_ID}/rawdataexports
Project Id and API Key(from place on screen) is proper too, but I am getting status 401...

Comment: So just for trying what happens if you click on `Create API Key`? Maybe what you see displayed is not the actual key? (Usually you see OAuth keyse.g. only printed out exactly once in the moment you create them (e.g. at Github))

Comment: "Generating a new API key will invalidate any existing keys. Do you still want to continue?"
If I will do it, then I have to replace old key in some things probably like tenjin

Comment: yeah ten don't ^^ can you confirm then that in your other locations (tenjin) you are using the same key (=> that it matches with what is displayed in the Dashboard)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I had to join Beta Unity Gaming Analytics to see option Analytics Settings and here I have proper key... Guys from Unity Team, you shoulnd't do something like that! Join to Beta program, temporarly free, are not obvious for everyone.